# Serial overclocking seems to occur when not attached to debugger on Windows CE device

Tags: serial-port, windows-ce

I have a problem with Windows CE 6 and a DIGI device with processor Freescale IMX51. I wrote an application in C # using the BSP of DIGI, to use the ARM eSPI (enhanced Serial Peripheral Interface).

Then using the functions issued by DIGI, in debug, I can active a OLED using SPI, but when I launch the application on the device, the OLED no longer works.

I have seen with an oscilloscope that when I load the application in debug mode the number of bits is correct, i.e., the clock has 8 rising edges, but when the application is launched from the device, the clock increases somewhat, that is, I see 9 bits. This also happens when I use the .exe from the debug directory.

I do not understand why this is happening.  Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: I don't doubt you lost most readers at 'in degub, active a OLED'.  If you can't explain what you expect and what you saw in plain English terms then you need help that's not available here.

Comment: @Ciccio, I've tried to edit the question to make it more legible.  If I have made any mistakes I apologize, please do make any necessary corrections.

Comment: So you're saying that when the debugger is attached, the SPI port is properly clocking out 8 bits of data, but when you detach the debugger it clocks out 9 bits? Have you tried with C to see if ti makes a difference (it shouldn't)?  Have you asked the OEM for a wroking example for using the driver?  This seems to be a very, very hardware-specific question.